# C++ How to return a caculated result data ptr to a vector param send into function?

Tags: c++

I have a customized object called `Tensor`, it was like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

class Tensor {
public:
  Tensor(DeviceType dev = DeviceType_kCPU);
  ~Tensor();


public:
  void *get_data();
  void *get_data() const;
  void set_data(void *data_ptr) { data_ = data_ptr; }


protected:
  DataType type_ = DataType_DT_FLOAT;
  DeviceType dev_ = DeviceType::DeviceType_kX86;
  void *data_ = nullptr;
  std::vector<size_t> dims_ = {};
};
```

I have a function called `Predict`:

```
bool predict(const std::vector<Tensor> &inputs,
                  std::vector<Tensor> &outputs, int batch_size,
                  std::string &err_msg) {

 auto tmp = m_layers_[j]->get_output();
    outputs[j].set_data(tmp);              // <--- How to assign tmp result to outputs

}
```

How to assign tmp result to outputs here? Since tmp is a local pointer, if I directly assing ptr value, outside the predict function, when I access the outputs, it will coredump.

How to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Usually if you want to fill a `vector` you do `outputs.emplace_back(tmp);`, depending on the class `outputs.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));`.

Comment: What does get_output() return and who is supposed to free it? The whole problem stems from the fact that ownership of the data is not clear, i.e who is supposed to release the data in the end? Is shared ownership needed here? It's not a question of how to assign but rather what the architecture is.

Comment: @alagner Hi, the buffer should be freeze by the net class, I want the last layer returned result from net assigned to my output tensor. so maybe also tensor should free the final result buffer.

Comment: @mch does std::move have a copy overhead? I want assign ptrs it to avoid memcpy.

Comment: If so, wrap it in `unique_ptr` with some custom deleter and return that. But keep in mind it'll be available in a single place only. `move` typically has some little overhead, similar to pointer assignment, i.e. properly done move operation should rebind internal pointers instead of copying what they point to at the price of the objects having a single owner.